# How do I get rid of brackets that are appearing around my Rails model error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  In my model, I set an error if one of my fields isn't valid ...

```
errors.add(:my_field, 'The field is not in the correct format')
```

and then in my view, I display the error like so ...

```
<% if !@user.errors[:my_field].empty? %><span class="profileError"> <%= @user.errors[:my_field] %></span><% end %>
```

When the error is displayed, it appears as

```
["The field is not in the correct format"]
```

How do I get rid of those brackets that appear around the error?  This seems like a really simple problem but I don't know how those things are creeping in there.

Comment: Change this `@user.errors[:my_field]` to `@user.errors[:my_field].first`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@user.errors[:my_field]` is an array of error messages.

To display all the errors, you can do...

```
@user.errors[:my_field].join(', ')
```

This will show single errors as you'd expect, and mulitple errors separated by commas.

e.g.

```
['not an integer', 'not less than ten']
```

becomes

```
not an integer, not less than ten
```

and

```
['not an integer']
```

becomes

```
not an integer
```

Answer (score 1):

In Rails the errors for any given attribute are an array since an attribute can fail multiple validations.

Normally you use `@user.errors.full_messages` and then iterate though all the error messages:

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
<ul>
  <%= @user.errors.full_messages.each do |m| %>
  <li><%= m %></li> 
  <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

In your case you can iterate though a specific key:

```
<% @user.errors[:my_field].each do |msg| %>
  <span class="profileError"><%= msg %></span>
<% end if @user.errors[:my_field].any? %>
```

Depending on what the desired output is you can also use `full_messages_for(:my_field)`. See the documentation for [ActiveModel::Errors](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-full_messages_for) for more examples.